# In which cases should I reference Silverlight.js file?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

By default a webapp using Silverlight has a `Silverlight.js` file included in a project and a JavaScript `Silverlight.js` file reference on the webpage which contains a Silverlight component.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Silverlight.js"></script>
```

Additionally it has the JavaScript function `onSilverlightError` included on the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
            appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }
 ...
```

Regarding `onSilverlightError` function, it seems that its use intended for the period of development and testing. Am I right? Should it be removed before going into production stage?

And regarding `Silverlight.js` reference. Should it be present on the page always? Or its use is recommended only if I want to implement a custom Silverlight Installation Experience?

Will `Silverlight.js` reference make sence by itself, without additional JavaScript code?

**Edited (added):** 
I found the [following on the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Silverlight.js depends on browser
>   implementation details that can change
>   between Silverlight releases. **For this
>   reason, the use of Silverlight.js is
>   not recommended.** However, if you
>   choose to use Silverlight.js, you
>   should periodically check for an
>   updated version from the
>   Silverlight.js page of the MSDN Code
>   Gallery.

Now I'm confused even more! Microsoft says that **the use of Silverlight.js is
not recommended**
or have I omitted something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the reference to the Silverlight.js file in your page (and include it with your application on the server).  It's used to check for the presence of Silverlight, and help with the installation experience (including with the default installation experience - automatically reloading the page once Silverlight is installed, determining whether the browser needs to be restarted, etc). You *can* remove it if you *really* want to, but you (and the users) are best off with it left in place.

Answer (score 0):

That JaveScript is a remnant from Silverlight 2
and the only reason it's there is in case the user doesn't have silverlight installed, it tells them where they can download it from.

so i would recommend to let it stay there, don't touch it, and don't mind it.